# I'm unable to turn on email delegation between my Google Apps domain accounts

Tags: gmail, google-workspace-for-business

I've created a second account (not an alias) that will delegate to my primary (as in, I'll enable delegation on the new account, delegating to the older one). My domain already has delegation enabled -- I have one other account delegating in the same way -- but this one won't turn on. When I attempt to enable delegation, the acceptance/confirmation email is sent to the receiving account, but clicking on the Accept link leaves me this error message:

> The account *****@***** or your own account is currently not allowed to set up this delegation. Please read the Help Center article to find out what may cause this error. You will not be able to view and send messages on behalf of *****@*****.

The new account is not waiting for a password change (confirmed) and is able to initiate the delegation workflow. The [helpdesk article on delegation](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/138350) doesn't tell me much, only this:

> In order to use delegation, both accounts must be enabled and verified, and neither account may require a password change on the next sign in. Otherwise, setup will fail with an error.

The new account isn't *verified* but frankly I'm not sure what that even means in this context.

How can I diagnose this delegation enablement issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bear in  mind that ...

> It can take up to 24 hours for new user accounts to appear in the
>   searchable Directory.

That means that features like email delegation could take up to 24 hours to be ready to be configured.

**References**
[Add users indiviually - Google Apps Help](https://support.google.com/a/answer/33310?hl=en)

Answer (score 5):

Yep, same problem. But [this Google Product Forums post](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/apps/4zoQzK5slJM) talks about 20-30 minutes of delay to get access to accept the invitation. It's right. You must be patient; delegation has slow propagation through Google's servers. I waited about one hour.

I afraid this feature is not implemented well for instant access, but is still good for holiday, multi-users account or similar use-cases.

Comment: Something for new "Google Workspace" admins... [GAM](https://github.com/jay0lee/GAM) can setup delegation instantly, with no confirmation sent to either user.